# Set div data attributes with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui-slider

I want to set slider-range min and max value via from ajax call. I tried set `attr` or data but all options not work. How can I set div attribute?

```js
$('#card-price-Div-Slide').attr('data-min','20');
$('#card-price-Div-Slide').attr('data-max','40');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="card-price-Div-Slide"
  class="slider-range ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"
  data-min="0"
  data-max="600"
  data-values="[0,600]"
  data-target="#price-range"
  data-label-min="#price-range-label-min"
  data-label-max="#price-range-label-max">Foo</div>
```

I also tried:

```
$('#card-price-Div-Slide').data('data-min','20');
$('#card-price-Div-Slide').data('data-max','40');
$('#card-price-Div-Slide').setAttribute('data-min','20');
```

Comment: It should be `.data("max")`.

Comment: @user1688401 I have checked your code and it's working as expected then what is the issue ?

Comment: Your first example works fine, as you can see in the snippet I edited in to your question. If it doesn't work for you check that there's no errors in the console. Also ensure you've include jQuery in the page and are running your jQuery code *after* the DOM has loaded. As a final note, be aware that `attr()` and `data()` perform very differently, so research them to ensure they meet your needs.

Comment: Calling the `attr` function on a jQuery object with `data-min` should work. It works in the example above too.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const element = document.querySelector('#card-price-Div-Slide');

element.setAttribute('data-min', 0);
element.setAttribute('data-max', 1000);

console.log(element.getAttribute('data-min'));
console.log(element.getAttribute('data-max'));
```

```html
<div id="card-price-Div-Slide"
  class="slider-range ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"
  data-min="5"
  data-max="600"
  data-values="[0,600]"
  data-target="#price-range"
  data-label-min="#price-range-label-min"
  data-label-max="#price-range-label-max">
  Foo
</div>
```